# wordpress redirect to single-post.php without page_id

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I'm new to wordpress and I try to do an url rewrite that looks like this

mysitename/adoption/petspecies/petname

Everything works fine until the petname part, I cannot redirect to my single-adoption.php file without hardcoding the page_id in the redirect url.

Here's how I do my custom post:

```
register_post_type(
'adoption',
array(
    'label' => 'Adoption',
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Adoption',
        'singular_name' => 'Adoption'
    ),
    'public' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'capability_type' => 'post',
    'supports' => array(
        'title',
        'editor',
        'thumbnail'
    ),
    'has_archive' => true,
    'rewrite' => array(
        'with_front' => true,
        'slug' => 'adoption',
    ),
)
```

);

```
register_taxonomy(
'espece',
'adoption',
array(
    'label' => 'espece',
    'labels' => array(
        'name' => 'Espèce',
        'singular_name' => 'Espèce'
    ),
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'rewrite'      => array('slug' => 'adoption', 'with_front' => true)
)
```

);

And here's my rewrite rule

```
function adoption_cpt_generating_rule($wp_rewrite) {
$rules = array();
$terms = get_terms( array(
    'taxonomy' => 'espece',
    'hide_empty' => false,
) );

$post_type = 'adoption';
foreach ($terms as $term) {           
    $rules['^adoption/' . $term->slug . '/([^/]*)/?'] = 'index.php?post_type='.$post_type.'&page_id=4252&adoption=$matches[1]&name=$matches[1]';}

// merge with global rules
$wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
```

}

```
add_filter('generate_rewrite_rules', 'adoption_cpt_generating_rule');
```

My code works fine with the page_id hardcoded in the redirect but stop working when I remove the page_id from the url.

Any advice to make it works without the page_id?